# Linq to SQL - Count on a different column than Group By column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, visual-studio-2015

How can I count numbers of orders for each customer in the following example **with** [LEFT Outer JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)?

**Models**:

```
Public class Customer
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
}

Public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ Query**:

```
var Query1 = from c in Customers
             join o in Orders into co
             from t in co.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {CustomerID = c.CustomerId, OrderID = (t == null ? 0 : t.OrderId)};
```

Comment: You don't need `left outer join` if all you need is the `Count`. `GroupJoin` is sufficient, e.g. in your example, remove `from t in co.DefaultIfEmpty()` and just use `co.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want how many order for each customer groub by using customerId then try this code

```
var Query1 = from c in Customers
                join o in Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                group o by o.CustomerId
                into g
                select new {CustomerId = g.Key, OrderCount = g.Count()};
```

Comment: You are using inner join. How about when using [LET OUTER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)?